# how to detect an embed and then resend it (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

so what i am trying to do is *detect when a bot sends an embed in a channel, and when it does detect this, to take that embed and resend it the same as it was sent as.*

For example, if the bot detects an embed sent in one channel, it will send that exact same embed in another channel. But the reason for this is because I want to take the embeds from multiple bots.

in **discordjs.guide** it says to use this code:

```
const receivedEmbed = message.embeds[0];
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(receivedEmbed).setTitle('New title');

channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

but this has not worked for me

Comment: What didn't work? Was there an error?

Comment: Your question is contradictory. Do you want to only resend the embed if it was sent by a bot? Do you want to resend the embed in the same channel or a different channel?

Comment: @DaemonBeast to resend the embed from a bot in one channel to another channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `channel` in the line `channel.send(exampleEmbed);` with an actual reference to a channel. Since you will be using the message event handler, you can get the channel the message was sent in using [`message.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel).

I have also added in a check to ensure that the message was sent by a bot and contains an embed.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  // check to ensure message was sent by bot and contains embed
  if (!message.author.bot || !message.embeds[0]) return;

  const receivedEmbed = message.embeds[0];
  const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(receivedEmbed).setTitle('New title');

  // send in same channel
  message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);

  // send in different channel
  client.channels.fetch(/* Channel ID */).then(channel => {
    channel.send(exampleEmbed);
  });
  // alternatively, you can use this (but the function must be asynchronous)
  const channel = await client.channels.fetch(/* Channel ID */);
  channel.send(exampleEmbed);
});
```

For more information on valid properties and methods, read the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

Comment: tysm for this <3

Answer (score 0):

The following code will check if the message has any embeds and will resend the first one.

```js
if (message.embeds) {
    message.channel.send({ embed: message.embeds.first() || message.embeds[0] })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const embed = message.embeds[0];
const editedEmbed = embed
.setTitle('Edited!')
.addField('Test Field!', 'This is a test', true);
message.channel.send(editedEmbed);
```

This worked perfectly fine for me.
The problem will be that you don't have a TextChannel selected. (message.channel)